# Algorithm to fill 2D array with the maximum value in the middle

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, matrix, 2d

Is there a methodical way to sort the values of a 2D square array with the maximum value in the middle and the minimum values at the edge?

Examples:

```
1 5 3 

8 9 6 

4 7 2
```

or:

```
4 8 1

6 9 5

2 7 3
```

I'm not sure which one would be the best, or how to do it for a nxn array (where n is an odd number).

Comment: Why are 5, 6, 7, 8 placed at their positions in your example and also why are 1,2,3,4 placed in the shown positions, why not other positions like 4 at the top right , 1 in left bottom etc.? How do you represent a 5 x 5 matrix with 1 - 25 numbers with the above scheme? If you can answer these, it is straightforward to implement.

Comment: Yes, but you don't do the sorting as a 2D array.  Rather, you sort the items linearly, and then place them by priority in their desired locations.

Comment: If the elements 1, 2, 3 and 4 can be in any corner in the example, then it's more of a partitioning than a sorting problem.

Comment: @Prune: In principle, the fact that there are many valid placements might mean that it can be done more efficiently without requiring a complete sorting of the values.

Answer (score 1):

Optimal time complexity: `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in your square. Here is the pseudocode:

- Assume that we have a square of size `m`.
- Put the elements in the square in a linear array (if they don't already saved as a linear array). Let's call it `a[1..n]`. Obviously, `n = m * m`.
- For a square of size `m * m`, there are `k = 4 * (m - 1)` elements on the border and `l = max(4 * (m % 2), 1)` values in the middle.
- Perform the [K'th element](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array/) algorithm two times:

  - First, call the minimum version (K'th smallest element) for the whole array `a[1..n]`, with parameter `k`. Now, the first `k` elements of the array, i.e. the subarray `a[1..k]` will contain smallest elements of the array.
  - Second, call the maximum version of this algorithm (K'th largest element) to the remaining subarray `a[k+1..n]` with parameter `l`. Now, the subarray `a[k+1..k+l]` will contain the largest elements of the array. And the remaining `a[k+l..n]` are all other elements.

Since [K'th element](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array/) is linear, the overall complexity of this algorithm is **linear** as well.

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the question. If someone wants to "sort an array with the minimum value at the beginning and the maximum value at the end", would you suggest that they find the minimum and maximum elements, swap them into the right positions, and leave the rest of the array unmodified?

Comment: @ruakh maybe, but the example doesn't show any ordering. Or perhaps it should be ordered by ring -- then my answer is wrong.

Comment: My understanding from the two examples is that for a 3x3 array, elements in the corners need to be less than elements on the middle of each side, which in turn need to be less than the very middle. But I'm not entirely sure how to extrapolate that to (say) a 25x25 array; I can think of multiple likely-seeming possibilities.